# CSS is not rendering on localhost, until i uploaded it to online server

Tags: css, localhost, wamp

I am having this weird problem. I tried searching on google for answers no one has ever asked such a question. The problem is that i make change to a css file named style.css and i go to browser to the localhost wamp link and refresh but the changes doesn't show. But when i upload the file to live server and refresh the live website i get that change and after i go to localhost website and refresh and the change happens. I tried clearing the cache but nothing changed.

Before that i came home today and i downloaded style.css from live server to my localhost, after that this problem started to happen. I am not sure though there is a relation between this event and why my file doesnt render on localhost wamp server.
I need your help please.

my css file style.css:

```
 .profile_more_arrow {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: solid 1px #d2cece;
background: url(../images/profileDownArrow.png) no-repeat;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 5% 20px;
background-position: 50% 10px;
```

}

Comment: How do you expect us to see what is wrong without code. Please add a relevant code snippet and maybe a directroy tree so we can see the problem

Comment: @SuperDJ I added the codes that i am trying but as i said the change show on localhost after i upload the file through FTP to live website

Comment: What isn't working?  Is just the background missing?  If so, it is a problem with your relative path.

Comment: @JenniferGoncalves thanks for your comment, well someone asked a question as a solution and the problem was with my path